# Enabling promiscuous mode (not monitor mode)

Tags: raspbian, networking, wifi

There are a lot of discussions on Raspbian and monitor mode, but I can only find scarce information about promiscuous mode. How do I put a Wifi interface in promiscuous mode? I'm looking to capture Wifi request probes while still associated with a network and otherwise not affecting that connection.

Current dongle is based on the Realtek RTL8188CUS chipset, but happy to buy any other dongle that makes this easier.

(Ultimately, the intent is to consume Wifi request probes in Python. Scapy seems like the appropriate choice.)

Comment: https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/369

Comment: Not sure, but it is entirely possible that the default drivers for Realtek (either RTL8188 or RTL8192) do not support promiscuous mode, and you'd need to recompile. Take a good look at the Github issue above and extrapolate.

Comment: how would I test if promiscuous mode works?

Comment: `ip link set wlan0 promisc on`, or try `tshark` or `wireshark` while you are connected.   You won't actually be able to see anything that way if the network is encrypted,  but I believe it will at least say if it can't put the device into promiscuous mode.